# My substr() is not working as intended

Tags: c++, string, substr

So I was trying to make text scroll on the screen, for example; h - he - hel - hell - hello

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "Welcome to the Password Vault!";
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < text.length(); x++) {
        cout << text.substr(x,x);
        _sleep(0100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
elccomome me toe to t to theto the Po the Pas the Passwthe Passworhe Password e Password Va Password VaulPassword Vault!assword Vault!ssword Vault!sword Vault!word Vault!ord Vault!rd Vault!d Vault! Vault!Vault!ault!ult!lt!t!!
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.961 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I wanted to output:

```
Welcome to the password vault!
```

Please help me!

Comment: Usually you need to send a character to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line, for example: `\r`.

Comment: Just so you know, C++11 has a standard `std::this_thread::sleep_for` function. And 0100 is an octal literal for 4, not a value of 100.

Comment: No `#include <string>` ?

Comment: @chris Don't you mean that `0100` is octal for *64*? :)

Comment: Second parameter of `std::substr()` is length, so are you sure about `cout << text.substr(x,x);` actually??

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Yeah 4 was binary. It's all 0s and 1s, what do you expect?

Answer (score 4):

You not only change the starting position, you also change the *length* of the substring you want to get, which is the second argument. If you just want to get one character at a time, the second argument should be `1`.

See e.g. [this `substr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I though (x,x) would do only x

Answer (score 2):

You are using substr wrong. You should replace the second parameter(x) with 1. The second parameter is the number of characters you want to "get". so do `text.substr(x,1);`
and you'll be all set :)

Answer (score 1):

it is because the substr() funtion requires two arguments namely starting string position and size of the string to be printed. So in the first iteration when substr(0,0) is executed and on the other iteration substr(1,1) prints 'e'
3rd iteration substr(2,2) prints "lc"
substr(3,3)- "com"
and so on.....